# IIS Loading wrong php.ini file?

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2003, php-ini

I'm not sure if that's what suppoused to happen but when i do `phpinfo()` 
I see that Loaded Configuration File is :

```
C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.4\php.ini
```

And not the one inside the php path (C:\PHP)

Is this how it should be? if not how can i control that?

Because my changes dosen't seem to be applied, EVEN when i edit that file.

I'm using PHP 5.4, IIS 6, Windows Server 2003.

I've followed a tutorial and set the following registery:

```
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP]
"IniFilePath"="C:\\PHP"
```

So it should load that one right?

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using IIS6, but maybe it could help you out to modify the default path of PHP in IIS  --> http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=85